# Why does my react app keep crashing on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, reactjs, heroku-toolbelt

I don't believe I have any config vars to add...
I added npm start in my package.json.

This is my server.js
    var app = express();

```
var compiler = webpack(config);

app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {noInfo: true, publicPath: config.output.publicPath}));
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));

app.use(express.static('./dist'));

app.use('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('client/index.html'));
});

var port = 8080;

app.listen(port, function(error) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log("Express server listening on port", port);
});
```

Heroku Activity Log

```
2016-06-27T05:26:06.606689+00:00 app[web.1]: > POM@0.3.1 start /app
2016-06-27T05:26:06.970312+00:00 app[web.1]: Express server listening on port 8080
2016-06-27T05:26:12.086607+00:00 app[web.1]: webpack built ece2fe8356b0c26f2ade in 5135ms
2016-06-27T05:26:44.560624+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=pom1.herokuapp.com request_id=77a8ad82-edc4-4dfb-a624-b1a92a5f008c fwd="173.239.65.34" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-06-27T05:27:04.972688+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably timing out because your app has not connected to the port that heroku provided it. You will be provided with a port number via an environment variable so you should declare your port like this

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
```

That will default to the port specified in the envionment variables (by heroku) and fall back on 8080 if none is set.

I believe the [getting started](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction) section on heroku touches on this and several other things you should know about deploying to heroku while also providing an [example application](https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started).